# Why does std::pow of a float and int invoke this overload?

Tags: c++, c++14, overload-resolution

The following:

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    float base = 2.0f;
    float result = std::pow(base, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Triggers a `-Wconversion` warning in case it is turned on. [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rGvRPgZXFtbM8WM8)

It seems that the `double` overload of `std::pow` is invoked, where I would expect the `float` overload to be chosen (with the `int` exponent being cast to `float`). Can someone who knows his overloads please explain why?

Comment: *where I would expect the float overload to be chosen* -- Why would you expect this overload to occur?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie because that does happen with e.g. base * 2, and it would be great to be able not to have to think about whether you're using a built-in operator or a function, and therefore whether you do or don't need to specify a float explicitly if you want the correct overload to run.

Comment: No problems in Visual Studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C++11, mixed argument [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) has any integral argument cast to double. The return type of the mixed argument functions is always `double` except when one argument is `long double` then the result is `long double`.

> ### [c.math]
>
> In addition to the double versions of the math functions in , C++ adds float and long double overloaded versions of these functions, with the same semantics.
>
> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:
>
> - If any argument corresponding to a double parameter has type long double, then all arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to long double.
> - Otherwise, if any argument corresponding to a double parameter has type double or an integer type, then all arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to double.
> - Otherwise, all arguments corresponding to double parameters are effectively cast to float.

So to sum up:

- One argument `long double` >> `long double`
- Both arguments `float` >> `float`
- Otherwise >> `double`

Comment: Is this just a general comment in the `std::pow` reference which is a result of the general overload rules, or is this special behavior implemented for `std::pow`?

Comment: @Danra: It holds for all math functions. I added the standard text.

Comment: Thanks, what I meant was whether this overload choosing behavior was due to the general C++ overloading resolution rules. It seems it isn't, so I guess either compilers have special overloading resolution behavior for these functions, or the standard library implementations do some hacks. Here's the demonstration about the same issue not occurring with my own defined function https://wandbox.org/permlink/l4rocKUvLEiXzdHY

Comment: @Danra It absolutely is because of the general C++ overloading rules.

Comment: Looking closer, the standard library trick being used is shown in the full warning text: "implicit conversion loses floating-point precision: 'typename std::__lazy_enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<float>::value && std::is_arithmetic<int>::value, std::__promote<float, int> >::type' (aka 'double') to 'float' [-Wconversion]"

Comment: @Danra: No there is not any magic overload resolution. Your example is missing the overloads demanded by the standard.

Comment: I see now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From cpp [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow)

> 7) A set of overloads or a function template for all combinations of
>   arguments of arithmetic type not covered by 1-3). If any argument has
>   integral type, it is cast to double. If any argument is long double,
>   then the return type Promoted is also long double, otherwise the
>   return type is always double.

"If any argument has integral type, it is cast to double" 
then it would call, converting your double to float.

```
float       pow( float base, float exp );
```